# Callbacks not called in amazon in app billing

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, in-app-billing

I've been stuck with this problem for many hours for now. I'm using the amazon in app billing library. I've successfully setup the Amazon App Tester and I'm using the sdktester.json file of the buttonclicker sample.

In my code I register the BasePurshasingObserver but callbacks are not called except onSdkAvailable.

PurchasingManager.registerObserver(new BillingObserver(context
                .getApplicationContext()));

class BillingObserver extends BasePurchasingObserver {

```
    public BillingObserver(Context arg0) {
        super(arg0.getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onGetUserIdResponse(GetUserIdResponse arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onGetUserIdResponse(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemDataResponse(ItemDataResponse arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onItemDataResponse(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseResponse(PurchaseResponse arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPurchaseResponse(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseUpdatesResponse(PurchaseUpdatesResponse arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPurchaseUpdatesResponse(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSdkAvailable(boolean arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSdkAvailable(arg0);
        PurchasingManager.initiateGetUserIdRequest();

    }

}
```

I can't get the object GetUserIdResponse because the callback onGetUserIdResponse is not called, even when I try to make a purchase I see the black interstitial, click by, see the transaction in the sdk tester but the onPurshaseResponse is not called neither.

I've put the receiver in the manifest, (there is a google billing receiver along with, I tried to remove it but nothing happened)

I removed progard.cfg files because I thought mybe the obfuscation was the problem without success. Any ideas, I'm running out of options :(

Comment: can you help me in implementing amazon in app purchase

Answer (score 2):

You must declare your receiver in the manifest and normaly it will work

```
<receiver android:name="*************************">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="*********************"
                    android:permission="**************" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```